# JS Regex: Remove Text in Parentheses if starts with digit

Tags: javascript, regex

Quick JS Regex question. I need a common Regex that will remove the parts in parentheses (incl. parentheses themelves) that start with a digit. Otherwise, that parentheses block stays.

Somehow the below doesn't work. I was expecting

- String 1
- String 2 (Parentheses)

```js
var str1 = "String 1 (12:30am - 5:00pm)";
var str2 = "String 2 (Parentheses) (3:00am - 3:10am)";

console.log(
  str1.replace(/\(^[0-9].*$\)/g, '').trim() + 
  "\n" + 
  str2.replace(/\(^[0-9].*$\)/g, '').trim()
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start [`^` and end `$` symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#boundaries) refer to the start and end of the input string. Remove them.

```js
var str1 = "String 1 (12:30am - 5:00pm)";
var str2 = "String 2 (Parentheses) (3:00am - 3:10am)";

function clearWithNumbers(str) {
  return str.replace(/\(\d.*\)/g, '').trim();
}

console.log(clearWithNumbers(str1));

console.log(clearWithNumbers(str2));
```